# Prevent flask session from updating on ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have a Flask site that uses Highcharts. There is a javascript timer that initiates and ajax request back to the server every several minutes to get the last several minutes of data and update the chart.

I also have the site setup to expire a session after 30 minutes of inactivity using this code:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True  
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30) 
    session.modified = True
```

However, since the ajax call runs every few minutes Flask will update the session time continually and therefore the session will never time out.

I want Flask to not update the session time when an ajax call is made. I've tried doing something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    if not re.match("^/api/", request.path):
        session.permanent = True  
        app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30) 
        session.modified = True
```

...where chart data is coming from any endpoint starting with /api/.

I've also set:

```
app.config.update(
    SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST = False
)
```